# Help identify a fern

Tags: identification, houseplants

I bought this fern from the super market, but they don't have any identification on it. Can you please help identify it so that I know how to take care of it.[image]

Comment: pnuts: the shape of the leaves looks very different from Boston Fern. Boston Fern looks long, sword like, this is more rounded.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely not a Boston, but this is from the fern family. The care is about the same as any fern. Keep it moist not wet. The temperatures should be 50°F-55°F at night, and up to 72°F in the day. Give it indirect light, not full sun. I love ferns but personally they're a little fussy for me.